# Docker-compose network wide extra hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know that it is possible to add additional entries to a services host list via the `extra_hosts` property:

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  somenet:
    external: true

services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage-
    container_name: mycontainername
    hostname: myhostname
    networks:
      - somenet

    extra_hosts:
      - "otherhost1.com:192.12.136.14"
      - "otherhost2.com:192.12.136.15"
```

Now I would like to be able to define extra_hosts for the whole network "somenet". Maybe something like:

```
docker network create somenet --extra-hosts "otherhost1.com:192.12.136.14 otherhost2.com:192.12.136.15"
```

Is there a docker native solution?

Comment: Did you found any solution for that back then?